# can't remove the reserved character?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to remove the reserved character but after calling my function it returns the same input..

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "erhan?test*.pdf";             

            remove(text);

            Console.WriteLine("This is your result : {0}", text);
            Console.ReadLine();           

        }

         private static string remove(string str){

             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             foreach (char c in str)
             {
                 if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '.' || c == '_' || c == ' ' || c == '%')
                 { sb.Append(c); }
             }
             return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are not updating the variable `text` (which to be honest you cannot do because string is immutable), but you are returning a new string from the function `remove`. Currently you are not using the returned value anywhere, so this value is effectively lost.

In order to make your code workyou need to assign your variable text to result of the function:

```
text = remove(text);
```

Comment: Just small clarification, it is not about immutable type in this case, it is about object reference I think.

Comment: @SonerGönül Thanks for noticing that, I updated the explanation

Comment: @DatVM Thanks for noticing that, I updated the explanation

Answer (score 3):

Chang this line

```
remove(text);
```

to

```
text = remove(text);
```

Because your function return a new `string` (built from `StringBuilder`), and you just call it without obtaining the result.